# casperjs images not loading when screenshot taken

Tags: image, phantomjs, casperjs, font-awesome, webfonts

when i take a screenshot with casperjs, the images are not showing. These are font awesome images.
The images do work when manually looking at the site.]

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use? Have you tried v2.0.0? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors. Can you include a screenshot of the broken images in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Are u taking screenshot using `capture()` ?

like this

```
casper.start('http://www.google.fr/', function() {
    this.capture('google.png', {
        top: 100,
        left: 100,
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    });
});
```

Comment: casper.then(function() {
      casper.capture(successful);
    });